# Algorithm to generate all possible arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been making an algorithm to generate all possible arrays with an given length and with only the digits up to and including 3, but it doensn't work, although it doensn't give an error. The code is as following:

```c++
template <typename t>
bool w (t begin, t end) {
while (begin != end) {
    end--;
    if (*end != 3) {
        *end++;
        return true;
    }
    else
        *end = 0;
}
return false;
}
```

Is someone getting what's wrong? Excuse me for my bad English, but it isn't is my mother tongue.

Comment: Well you know, the fact is doesn't give an error just means there's no compiling or linking problem. In other words, the program does do something, but apparently not what you want it to.

Comment: Also, your code is badly indented, and why are you using templates if you just want to do what you said you want to? Also, nowhere in the code do you even declare an array!

Answer (score 0):

`*end++;` doesn't do what you want as it does `*(end++)` so just `end++`.
With better warning settings, you would have:

> warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
>   *end++;
>   ^

Use `++*end;` or `(*end)++;`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Pd3SPp).